# FPC Whole Program Optimization

Tags: pascal, freepascal, fpc

How can I use **Whole Program Optimization** feature in Free Pascal 2.7.1 on Windows?

I get this error:

> Project1.dpr(92,1) Fatal: Cannot find "nm.exe" or "" to extract symbol
>   liveness information from linked program

Comment: There might be something wrong with your installation. FPC as well as lazarus come with an nm.exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the WPO is trying to extract symbols from your executable using `NM`. `NM` is not available for Windows.

The good news is, Windows has [DumpBin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) instead. I think you can use this directly in place of `NM`.